# Notification push from External System

Tags: notification

I have a Canvas app that is connected to an external system. A User will use the external app to request a record is created that can take several minutes. I'd like to be able to have the external system notify the user using Salesforce's notifications (bell icon alert or a banner) when the process is done.

What is the best approach to accomplish using Apex or a declarative tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your external system once done processing has to call Salesforce and tell that process is done. One way I can see is using customNotificationAction. They also have a rest endpoint that can be called from 3rd party.

```
curl --include --request POST \
--header "Authorization: Authorization: Bearer 00DR...xyz" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{ "inputs" :
  [
  {
    "customNotifTypeId" : "0ML1k0000008OIFGA2",
    "recipientIds" : ["0051k000001G0f5AAC"],
    "title" : "Case Closed!",
    "body" : "Your High Priority Case has been Closed.",
    "targetId" : "5001k00000BrdQ9AAJ"
  }
  ]
}' \
"https://gs0.salesforce.com/services/data/v46.0/actions/standard/customNotificationAction"
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/06/get-buildspiration-with-custom-notifications-in-summer-19.html

Comment: Great, thanks Pranay!